# Retrieve nested keys Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app developed in Swift that uses Firebase as backend.

```
MESSAGES
   -KW83KXYFzNgo-ibxKQV
        --dateSent: "2016-09-09 12:30:23+0000"
        --smiley:"smiley1"
        --userID:"0QggCGYr46fcz3ak8tcQjsyZ9sJ2"
Users 
  -- 0QggCGYr46fcz3ak8tcQjsyZ9sJ2
      --name: "john"
      --photo:"photoURL"
```

I want to retrieve the name of users and display them with messages, I try this code:

```
self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
self.ref.child("messages").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in        
   if let snapshotValue = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: Constants.Messages.senderId).value {
     FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")
         .child(snapshotValue as! String).observe(.value, with: {userSnapshot in
            if let userSnapshotValue = userSnapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                self.usernames.append(userSnapshotValue[Constants.UserFields.nickName] as! String)
            }
        })
```

The result is this:

```
0QggCGYr46fcz3ak8tcQjsyZ9sJ2
[]
VAMFsmkM7DObJ0x752eVT1WuICe2
[]
0QggCGYr46fcz3ak8tcQjsyZ9sJ2
[]
VAMFsmkM7DObJ0x752eVT1WuICe2
[]
0QggCGYr46fcz3ak8tcQjsyZ9sJ2
[]
VAMFsmkM7DObJ0x752eVT1WuICe2
[]
```

So the code retrieves the keys, but didn't execute the nested query. Any propositions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified and more verbose version of what you want:

```
    let usersRef = ref.child("users")
    let postsRef = ref.child("posts")

    postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (postSnap) in

        let postDict = postSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        let msg = postDict["msg"]!
        let userId = postDict["user_id"] as! String

        let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(userId)
        thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { userSnap in

            let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let userName = userDict["name"] as! String
            print("msg: \(msg)")
            print("  fromUid: \(userId)")
            print("  userName: \(userName)")
        })
    })
```

and the output

```
msg: some message from uid_0
  fromUid: uid_0
  userName: Bill
msg: some message from uid_1
  fromUid: uid_1
  userName: Leroy
```

and the Firebase structure

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Bill"
  uid_1
    name: "Leroy"
posts
  post_0
   msg: "some message from uid_0"
   user_id: "uid_0"
  post_1
   msg: "some message from uid_1"
   user_id: "uid_1"
```

Comment: the problem is the nested query is async so the result will be different as expected , I try to make separate queries , the query of the user is executed when i create the cell of tableview but i still have problems with the results given specifically when i scroll up and down quickly

Comment: @TawfikBouabid That is not correct. The asynchronous nature of Firebase can make code executing *outside* the closure run 'slower' than the code within the closure. If you look at the answer, the print statements only occur within the closure so the variables must contain data so the timing is fine. Your problem is at a higher level in that you should not be accessing Firebase when you create the cell. You should access Firebase to populate an *array* which then serves as the datasource for your tableView. The cells should *only* access that array, which makes it very responsive.